# How to write arraylist data to database in silverstripe

Tags: php, arraylist, silverstripe

```
$arraylist1 = new ArrayList();
foreach ($orders as $order){
    $email1= $order->cus1()->Email;
    $email2= $order->cus2()->Email;
    $email3= $order->cus3()->Email;
    $arraylist1->push($email1);
    $arraylist1->push($email2);
    $arraylist1->push($email3);
}
debug::show($arraylist1);
$dbobject1->Emails = $arraylist1;
$dbobject1->write();
```

`$arraylist1` print the relevant emails in the browser. And i want to put these data to database. Above code given error like

> DataObject::setField: passed an object that is not a DBField

Comment: yes $arraylist1 print the values

Comment: but couldn't write to the database

Comment: $dbobject1->Emails = $arraylist1;
$dbobject1->write();

Comment: output is a emaillist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. It is not possible to write objects to the database.

But... to answer your question.
You can use [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). As per documentation: `Generates a storable representation of a value`.

However, this is **not** a 'good practise'.

You can use it like this:

```
//store
$dbobject1->Emails = serialize($arraylist1);
//retrieve
$emails = unserialize($dbobject1->Emails);
```

On a sidenote, your code indicates a few flaws, like not have a `has_many` relation but instead a few `has_one`'s. If you would have a `has_many` relation with `Customers` you could call `$dbobject1->Customers()->column('Email');` to get a list of emails.

**UPDATE**
As [Robbie Averill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2812842) suggests, JSON encoding might be a better solution:

```
//store
$dbobject1->Emails = json_encode($arraylist1->toNestedArray());
//retrieve
$emails = json_decode($dbobject1->Emails);
```

Comment: JSON encoding is probably prefereable to serialisation to prevent object instantiation vulnerabilities

Comment: Yeah I think your suggestion to use a has_may is much better =)

Comment: Thanks  Robbie Averill  and Fatal Error